# How to utilize a load more button to a filtered list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a list of items which are only displayed when they match a selected option in the option menu as illustrated in the code snippet. The following happens when the code is run:

- `option` filter shows all the items.
- `option-1` filter shows only `option-1` items.
- `option-2` filter shows only `option-2` items.
- `option-3` filter shows only `option-3` items.
- `option-4` filter shows only `option-4` items.

The `active-option` text is changed  to the presently active option(filter).

There are some changes I would like to effect to the code:

These items will be dynamically created and will get so much and hence, I do not want to display them all at once and **only want them to display in a set of fours**.

If there are no items that match a particular "option-filter", it should display the `no-content-container` by giving it a class of "`active`"

There is a `load-more` button and when it is clicked, the following should happen:

- the next four items that match the active chosen option(filter) should be displayed.
- In the case that the remaining items that match the filter are less than four, it should display all the remaining items.
- If there are no remaining items that belong to that filter, the `load more` button should disappear
- **If a new option filter is selected even after the `load-more` button has disappeared for the previously chosen option filter, the `load-more` button should reappear for the newly selected option contents.**

**Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you all**

```js
var options = $('.menu-option');
var active_option = $('.active-option');
var option_contents = $('div.option');
options.click(function(event){
  option_contents.hide();
  active_option.text(event.target.innerText);
  option_contents.filter('.' + event.target.id).show();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.option-box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 20px 0 30px 20px;
}

.menu-option {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

.option-box,
.menu-option {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  padding: 30px 20px;
}

.option {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.load-more {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: goldenrod;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.no-content-container {
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.no-content-container.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option-box">
   <span class="active-option">All Options</span>
</div>
<div class="options-container">
   <span class="menu-option" id="option">All Options</span>
   <span class="menu-option" id="option-1">Option 1</span>
   <span class="menu-option" id="option-2">Option 2</span>
   <span class="menu-option" id="option-3">Option 3</span>
   <span class="menu-option" id="option-4">Option 4</span>
  <span class="menu-option" id="option-5">Option 5</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="option option-1">
      Option 1 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-2">
      Option 2 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-3">
      Option 3 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-4">
      Option 4 Content
   </div>
  <div class="option option-1">
      Option 1 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-2">
      Option 2 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-3">
      Option 3 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-4">
      Option 4 Content
   </div>
  <div class="option option-1">
      Option 1 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-2">
      Option 2 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-3">
      Option 3 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-4">
      Option 4 Content
   </div>
  <div class="option option-1">
      Option 1 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-2">
      Option 2 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-3">
      Option 3 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-4">
      Option 4 Content
   </div>
  <div class="option option-3">
      Option 3 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-4">
      Option 4 Content
   </div>
  <div class="option option-1">
      Option 1 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-2">
      Option 2 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-3">
      Option 3 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-4">
      Option 4 Content
   </div>
  <div class="option option-1">
      Option 1 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-2">
      Option 2 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-3">
      Option 3 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-4">
      Option 4 Content
   </div>
  <div class="option option-1">
      Option 1 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-2">
      Option 2 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-3">
      Option 3 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-4">
      Option 4 Content
   </div><div class="option option-1">
      Option 1 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-2">
      Option 2 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-3">
      Option 3 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-4">
      Option 4 Content
   </div>
  <div class="option option-4">
      Option 4 Content
   </div>
  <div class="option option-1">
      Option 1 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-2">
      Option 2 Content
   </div>
  <div class="option option-4">
      Option 4 Content
   </div>
  <div class="option option-1">
      Option 1 Content
   </div>
   <div class="option option-2">
      Option 2 Content
   </div>
   
   <a href="" class="load-more">load more</a>
  <div class="no-content-container">No content matches the selected option</div>
</div>
```